# Magento adding commas into download link

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

Having some issues with Magento adding commas to a download link. Safari, Firefox, and Internet Explorer are fine with escaping the commas and downloading the file, but Google Chrome doesn't escape the commas and when the download link is clicked just displays a white page with no download occurring.

I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this from occurring?

This is the format of the link that Magento is distributing:

> /store/downloadable/download/link/id/MC4zMTI1NjkwMCAxMzc5NTE3MzcyMTIxOTkzMDI3NzQwNQ,,/

I do have other downloadable products that work just fine (including products with multiple download links).

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the file name in [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Comment: @SteveRobbins I have tried that, but I end up getting unusable links on the customer frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Magento's downloadable core extension replaces '+/=' with '-_,'. See line 115 in file /app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Observer.php. You can modify this behavior with a local overwrite. However, try adding a new product and deleting the old one as this will change the product Id which is used as an input in the base64_encode() - maybe it can help.

Comment: Yep, that looks to be the issue. I had looked in there before but must have glossed over that section. Thanks for your input!